# How to change /boot/efi containing both Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I got a 500 GB hard drive on my laptop, and the storage partitions are a bit messed up which I didn't focus on while installing Ubuntu (when I changed to EFI). So I have this 100 MB EFI partition between my Ubuntu 20.04 install And some free space. For the time being I made the space a partition so I can have enough space, but the reason I've so less storage in Ubuntu home directory is because I didn't think I would daily drive it.
[image]

So is there any way I can like move the /boot/efi to another partition thats like at the end of the disk, so it doesn't interfere with my partitions. I also want to keep the Windows 10 install because one of my project only works on Windows (sigh).

Comment: It's not possible, if you wish to delete it then you won't be able to boot into Windows 10 anymore along side Ubuntu (I'm guessing you have dual-boot, installed Ubuntu side by side with Win10). EFI partition is primary partition and contains critical/crucial boot data for Windows 10. Read [EFI Partition vs /boot partition](https://superuser.com/questions/520068/efi-partition-vs-boot-partition)

Comment: Oh man, that's unfortunate, but can I like, increase size of /boot/efi and from the games partition then reduce it so I have unallacated space that I can allocate to `/` . Can I do it without messing up Windows 10

Comment: It is possible to move the EFI partition, you just need to be prepared to fix any boot issues that arise. I would use GParted to copy the EFI partition to a USB key delete the old partition, and move/merge the others, then copy the EFI partition back. Always backup anything you cannot afford to lose first

Comment: Make sure in future you increase EFI size partition to atleast 512MB , so you  wont have  problems with low space with regards to install o/s. Also agree with the advise PonJar has given.